# Assign a dynamic default value for function variable?

Tags: python, arguments

I have a function which creates a compound string based on how many times the user wants to input the string:

```
def string_maker(string_list, repeat_list):
  final_string = ''
  for i in range(len(string_list)):
    for _ in range(repeat_list[i]):
      final_string += string_list[i]
  return final_string
```

So, for example, `string_maker(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 1])` outputs `abbc`.

I want to make it so that if the user doesn't input a list for the `repeat_list` argument, it defaults to all 1s. This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
def string_maker(string_list, repeat_list = None):
  if repeat_list == None:
    repeat_list = [1] * len(string_list)
  final_string = ''
  for i in range(len(string_list)):
    for _ in repeat_list[i]:
      final_string += str
  return final_string

print(string_maker(['a', 'b', 'c']))
```

However, I receive an error saying `'int' object is not iterable`, even though the new snippet I included returns the appropriate list `[1, 1, 1]`. Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Just to note that your inner loop isn't using `range` as you did originally...

Comment: The variable (?) `str` is undefined in the second code snippet (it's the name of a built-in class, so you shouldn't be using it a variable name in the first place).

Comment: The problem is this line: `for _ in repeat_list[i]:`... `repeat_listp[i]` will be an `int` object, and you cannot iterate over int object, as the error clearly states.

Comment: Thanks everything, this was a terrible example of my not being able to copy and paste my own code properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` method is a much more efficient way to build this list.

```
from itertools import repeat


def string_maker(string_list, repeat_list=repeat(1)):
    return ''.join([x*n for x, n in zip(string_list, repeat_list)])
```

`repeat(1)` provides an infinite stream of 1s; `zip` only uses as many of them as it needs to pair with elements of `string_list`. `x*n` creates a string consisting of `n` repeated occurrences of `x`.

```
>>> string_maker(list("abc"))
'abc'
>>> string_maker(list("abc"), [1,2,1])
'abbc'
```